# Find String & Replace Decimal Value After It

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

I am trying to find out a way of using sed or awk that will find a known string, lets say "name" in a known file name, lets say "filename.txt". After every occurence of the string, "name" there is a space and then there is a decimal value that can range from 0.00001 - 999.99999, with that many numbers both before and after the deicmal. In most cases, the value is of the type, X.XXXXX . This value always comes after the string "name". I want to be able to replace that decimal value that comes after "name" with a value I give it, lets say "mydecimalvalue".

Similarly, if "name" does not exist in "filename.txt" I would like to add it after the string "name1", which is known and will be there in every "filename.txt". Any ideas? An explanation would be much appreciated as well, as I can easily get lost in the regular expressions and the option meanings.

For example, filename.txt may look like:

```
    garbage 10.34420
    name1 34.23000
    name 8.32345
    moregarbage 4.23324
```

I want to replace "name 8.32345" with "name 15.43200" for example. If "name" followed by any type of value does not exist anywhere in the file, I want to write "name 15.43200" right after "name1 34.23000". If "name" does exist in the file, it is ok to assume that it will only exist once in the entire file.
Thanks!

Comment: please consider replacing this elaborate description with some sample data that covers the cases you need to support AND the required output for that data. Note that you can use the {} tool in the format bar to indent code and data. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
if grep -q '\<name\>' filename.txt; then
  sed -i 's/\<\(name\) [0-9.]+/\1 15.43200/' filename.txt
else
  sed -i '/\<name1\>/a\
name 1543200' filename.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
name=1.23456 
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\<name\> [^\n]*/name '"$name"'/;t;s/\(\([^\n]\+\)\<name1\> [^\n]*\)/\1\n\2name '"$name"'/' file
```